# Radiobuttonlist CSS Styling

Tags: html, css, radiobuttonlist

Below is my code and screenshot. How to fix this ?

This is a Modal dialog. It is displaying border around the radio button and text is displaying after that. I don't want border and want text to display beside radio button.

```
 <tr>
    <td>
      <b>Choose:</b>
       <br />
       <br />
       <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbAdApprovalStatus" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical" RepeatLayout="Flow"                        OnTextChanged="rbAdApprovalStatus_OnTextChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
        <asp:ListItem Value="Approved">Approved</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Approved w/ Requirements">Approved w/ Requirements</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Declined">Declined</asp:ListItem>
      </asp:RadioButtonList>
     </td>
   </tr>
```

[image: Radiobutton list Style]

Comment: at least you should say what's wrong with it first? the ss is not enough to tell the exact problem.

Comment: I agree with @KingKing - What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Agreed, but I'm pretty sure it's the crazy boxes around the radio buttons.

Comment: @KingKing  Hello, I am sorry. I just edited the post with the issue. I don't want border and want text to display beside radio button.

Comment: And, what does your css look like?

Comment: I'm going to assume you have something like `input { /* styles meant for text inputs*/ }` which is also applying to your radios and checkboxes (and technically, hidden inputs as well).

Comment: @WesleyMurch Can we fix this in td ?

Comment: You have to adjust your CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

There are hundreds of different ways to do what you'd like to do.

Here's an old fiddle that might get you started - just click on the square - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AcG2Y/1/).

JS

```
var $dialogpopup = $( ".hiddenimagediv" ).dialog({
                  autoOpen: false,
                  height: 'auto',
                  width: 'auto',
                  position: {my: "top middle",
                             at: "top middle",
                             of: ".imagediv"},
                  title:"Finalize"});

$('.imagediv').click(function(){
                               $dialogpopup.dialog('open');
                               });
```

Comment: What, precisely, made you feel a jQuery solution was appropriate to a problem tagged with HTML and CSS?